# Search for a specific number using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd
      import re

      df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_01': ['00001RX', '8254TX sensor', '8Actuador', '8 Sensor'],
                         'Column_02': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']})
```

I would like to go through 'Column_01' and check if the line starts with the number 8. If for is true I need a new column 'Column_03' to receive the word 'FINDING'. Otherwise, receive 'NaN'.

I tried to implement the following code. However, it is wrong:

```
     df['Column_03'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'FINDING'
                       if re.match(r'\d[8]', x['Column_01'])
                       else np.NaN, axis = 1)
```

My output:

```
        Column_01        Column_02  Column_03
         00001RX            AAA      NaN
         8254TX sensor      BBB      NaN
        8Actuador           CCC      NaN
         8 Sensor           DDD      NaN
```

The desired output is:

```
         Column_01       Column_02  Column_03
         00001RX            AAA      NaN
         8254TX sensor      BBB      FINDING
        8Actuador           CCC      FINDING
         8 Sensor           DDD      FINDING
```

Comment: Why not just use `str.startswith('8')`?

Answer (score 3):

the issue with your code is it looks for any pattern where you have a digit [0-9] followed by an 8. what you mean to have is

```
df['Column_03'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'FINDING'
                   if re.match(r'^8', x['Column_01'])
                   else np.NaN, axis = 1)
```

Which will check that 8 is the first character. the `^` means start of the line and then you can just put 8.

as @Ch3steR said you may also use `str.startswith('8')`

#### Whole Example

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_01': ['00001RX', '8254TX sensor', '8Actuador', '8 Sensor'],
                     'Column_02': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']})

df['Column_03'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'FINDING'
               if re.match(r'^8', x['Column_01'])
               else np.NaN, axis = 1)
print(df)

>>>
       Column_01 Column_02 Column_03
0        00001RX       AAA       NaN
1  8254TX sensor       BBB   FINDING
2      8Actuador       CCC   FINDING
3       8 Sensor       DDD   FINDING
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
df['Column_03'] = ['Finding' if i.startswith('8') else np.nan for i in df['Column_01']]
print(df)
```

---

```
       Column_01 Column_02 Column_03
0        00001RX       AAA       NaN
1  8254TX sensor       BBB   Finding
2      8Actuador       CCC   Finding
3       8 Sensor       DDD   Finding
```

---

or using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['Column_03'] = np.where(df['Column_01'].str.startswith('8'),'Finding',np.nan)
```